# Tomcat 7 /WEB-INF/ directory mapping

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml

I want to map all requests to a specific servlet but Tomcat won't let me map the /WEB-INF/ directory.

My web.xml file.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.TestServlet</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This works fine until you request a page in the /WEB-INF/ directory (gives a 404).   Is there any way to map everything, including the /WEB-INF/ directory to a servlet?

I also tried mapping the servlet with /WEB-INF/* and it had no effect.

Comment: maybe duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093446/why-request-which-start-with-web-inf-cannot-be-mapped-to-a-servlet-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot access files in `WEB-INF` from outside directly.

You will have to have a `html` or a `jsp` file outside which would redirect the request to files inside `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: I don't want to access anything in the /WEB-INF/ directory.  I just want to intercept the request from the directory and process it with my own servlet instead of having an automatic 404.

Comment: It's hardwired in to the container. The container doesn't even get that far. It's basically a security precaution.

Answer (score 1):

As per the tomcat standard, you need to put all your *.html, *.jsp, etc in the application root directory. /WEB-INF directory is mainly used to contain your web.xml, classes and libs but not jsp/htmls. You can't directly navigate to any files/artifacts placed under WEB-INF directory (also valid for META-INF).

> This is a security feature of the servlet engine: content under
>   WEB-INF is protected and not accessible from "outside" via URLs. Else,
>   anybody could read sensitive details like application/database
>   configuration, etc. by just assembling appropriate URLs.

You need to follow the guidelines about packaging your web application, read more here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html